# SwiftUI: Add ClearButton to TextField

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add a ClearButton to TextField in SwiftUI when the particular TextField is selected.

The closest I got was creating a `ClearButton` `ViewModifier` and adding it to the `TextField` using `.modifer()`

The only problem is `ClearButton` is permanent and does not disappear when `TextField` is deselected

```
TextField("Some Text" , text: $someBinding).modifier(ClearButton(text: $someBinding))

struct ClearButton: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            Button(action: {
                self.text = ""
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I would guess because the accepted answer is a modification of Cam's existing code. It seems that it is also more robust, updating based on the data source itself, rather than tracking a new derived state

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `ZStack` to position the clear button appear inside the `TextField`.

```
TextField("Some Text" , text: $someBinding).modifier(ClearButton(text: $someBinding))

struct ClearButton: ViewModifier
{
    @Binding var text: String

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View
    {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing)
        {
            content

            if !text.isEmpty
            {
                Button(action:
                {
                    self.text = ""
                })
                {
                    Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator))
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: clear button inside TextView]

Comment: It's better to replace ZStack with HStack. Otherwise long text will go under the image.

Comment: Alas it doesn't. I think the button no longer triggers on newer iOS versions.

Comment: TextField("name", text: $newFolderName)
                        .onAppear {
                            UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
                        }
this worked for me

Answer (score 40):

Use `.appearance()` to activate the button

```
var body: some View {
    UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    return TextField(...)
}
```

For reuse try with this:

```
func TextFieldUIKit(text: Binding<String>) -> some View{
    UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    return TextField("Nombre", text: text)
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I'm curious how you found this solution??

Comment: In combination with a 'TapGesture()' it doesn't clear the text!

Comment: @PeterKreinz, that's because `TapGesture()` catches the tap instead of clear button, try `.simultaneosGesture(...)`

Comment: This solution has side effects. If you use UIAppearance you will set the clearButtonMode for ALL UITextField instances, not only the one you are trying to change.

Comment: doesn't clear the text iOS 16 (no tap gesture)

Answer (score 32):

=== solution 1(best): Introspect https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

```
import Introspect
TextField("", text: $text)
    .introspectTextField(customize: {
        $0.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    })
```

=== solution 2: ViewModifier

```swift
public struct ClearButton: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String

    public init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary) 
                .opacity(text == "" ? 0 : 1)
                .onTapGesture { self.text = "" } // onTapGesture or plainStyle button
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
@State private var name: String

...

Form {
    Section() {
        TextField("NAME", text: $name).modifier(ClearButton(text: $name))
    }
}
```

=== solution 3: global appearance

```
UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
```

Comment: I've tried to use this but the bound value doesn't change. Within the `ClearButton` block, the value of `text` is the value of the TextField the first time I press it. Then, its indeed cleared, but the cleared `text` value is not set on the TextField. So, I'm trying to understand why we need the `_text` attribute. I'm still trying to understand SwiftUI so sorry it its obvious.

Comment: Why is an image with on tap better?

Comment: @TruMan1 I found it better to use an image with onTapGesture because of a disabled TextField I had in my HStack (next to the TextField using the clear button). Whenever I tapped the disabled field, it cleared out my non-disabled field next to it with the clear button. Something with the placeholder and the ZStack... regardless this might be a viable solution for others with a similar scenario over the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found this [answer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swift/adding-a-clear-button-to-a-textfield/12079/18824) from [@NigelGee](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/users/NigelGee) on "Hacking with Swift".

```
.onAppear {
    UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
}
```

It really helped me out.

Answer (score 7):

You can add another `Binding` in your `modifier`:

```
@Binding var visible: Bool
```

then bind it to opacity of the button:

```
.opacity(visible ? 1 : 0)
```

then add another `State` for checking `textField`:

```
@State var showClearButton = true
```

And lastly update the textfield:

```
TextField("Some Text", text: $someBinding, onEditingChanged: { editing in
    self.showClearButton = editing
}, onCommit: {
    self.showClearButton = false
})
.modifier( ClearButton(text: $someBinding, visible: $showClearButton))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am using multiple `TextField` as part of a `Form`, is there a solution that doesn't involve creating a showClearButton `@State` for every `TextField` ?

Comment: Yes, creating custom `View` for your custom `TextField`.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but this will let you show/hide the button based on the `text` contents:

```
HStack {
    if !text.isEmpty {
        Button(action: {
            self.text = ""
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I came up with

```
//
//  ClearableTextField.swift
//
//  Created by Fred on 21.11.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ClearableTextField: View {
    
    var title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(_ title: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.title = title
        _text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            TextField(title, text: $text)
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .onTapGesture {
                text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ClearableTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @State static var text = "some value"
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Form {
            // replace TextField("Original", text: $text) with
            ClearableTextField("Clear me", text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to Just do like this

`TextField("Please enter", text: $viewModel.label).onAppear { UITextField.appearance().clearButtonMode = .whileEditing }`

Comment: If you do this on a `View`, all your text fields in other views will also start showing clear button while editing, once this text field appears in the lifecycle of the app. This is not great, if we only change the behaviour on a particular `TextField`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have **multiple** TextField and also want to tap on the screen and **hide** the proper clear button you can do like this:

```
    struct ClearTextFiledButton: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState private var showDeleteButton: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .focused($showDeleteButton)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                if showDeleteButton {
                    Button {
                        text = ""
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing,8)
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 0 : 1)
                }
            }
    }
    
}

extension View {
    func showClearButton(_ text: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(ClearTextFiledButton(text: text))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a clean Textfield in SwiftUI, with no overlapping between user inputted text and clear button, here an example:

```
                ZStack(alignment: .trailing)
                {
                    TextField("Tapez une url", text: $myViewModel.urlString, onCommit: {
                        // action
                    })
                    .submitLabel(.done)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 3)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .frame(height: 30, alignment: .top)
                    .background(.white, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 5))
                    .overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                            myViewModel.urlString = ""
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                            .opacity(myViewModel.urlString.isEmpty ? 0 : 1)
                            .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 5),
                        alignment: .trailing
                    )
                }
```