# How do I add closures to Viewmodifiers in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am using the ClearButton ViewModifier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58896723/14139338)

```
.modifier(ClearButton(text: $someBinding))
```

But I want to run a function after clear textfield. Like this or similar

```
.modifier(ClearButton(text: $someBinding)) {
      print("")
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function as a parameter like this:

```
struct ClearButton: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String
    var action: () -> Void = {} // pass the function here

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            content

            if !text.isEmpty {
                Button(action: {
                    self.text = ""
                    action() // call the `action` here
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator))
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and apply this modifier to your TextField:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Some Text", text: $text)
            .modifier(
                ClearButton(text: $text) {
                    print("TextField cleared")
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to skip the label for the trailing closure, the `action` parameter must come last.

Comment: Can we make this optional?

Comment: @Robert Sure, I updated my answer. You can replace `{}` with the default behaviour. You may also use `var action: (() -> Void)?` but this requires unwrapping the optional later.

Comment: Thank you @pawello2222 I tried like this but it doesnt work. `.modifier(ClearText(text: $name, action: { print("234") }))`

Comment: @Robert Not sure what you're doing. You probably didn't call `action()`. I updated my answer with a more detailed solution.

Comment: I am realy sory. I didn't call action. I added and It works great. I cannot thank you enough.